In django class base view whenever I logged in, my user log in successfully but get this error page:Page not found (404)
I tried class base view in my blog website authorlogin. Every time I log in though, my author gets logged, but get a page of error. I have just convert login into class-based view but my author profile is function based view.
The error message I get:

Page not found (404)
Request Method:   GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/
Using the URLconf defined in blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
author/
category/
post/
[name='base']
The current path, accounts/profile/, didn’t match any of these.

main urls.py
urlpatterns = [
   
    path('author/',include('author.urls')),
]

authorlogin url
urlpatterns = [
    path('author.login/',views.authorlogin.as_view(),name='login'),
     path('profile',views.authorprofile,name='profile')
        
]

views.py
class authorlogin(LoginView):
    template_name='login.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request,'Welcome mr.{name}')
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request,'Logged in information incorrect')
        return super().form_invalid(form)
    

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) :
        context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['type']='login'
        return context

    
@login_required
def authorprofile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
       data=Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
       return render (request,'profile.html',{'data':data})
    else:
        return redirect('login')

I tried that after get login it take me directly to profile page not an error page

in project settings .py i added :  LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile'    the problem solved        you can also use def get_success_url(self) function also for solving this problem

It seems like the default redirect URL for your authorlogin class-based view is causing the issue. By default, the LoginView in Django redirects to /accounts/profile/ after a successful login, but this URL does not exist in your URL patterns.
You can solve this by specifying a next parameter or setting the success_url in your authorlogin view to redirect to the correct profile page. Here’s how you can update your authorlogin class-based view to redirect to the author profile page after login:
# views.py

from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Post

class authorlogin(LoginView):
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, f'Welcome {self.request.user.username}')
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, 'Login information incorrect')
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profile')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['type'] = 'login'
        return context

@login_required
def authorprofile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        data = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'data': data})
    else:
        return redirect('login')

make Sure Urls.py correctly configured.
